# What is the way to write the new get and set properties in C# 6.0 when has more sentences?

Tags: c#-6.0

in the last C# versions of the properties get and set with more sentences the way to write is:

```
ObservableCollection<Product> products;
public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
{
   get
   {
     return products;
   }
   set
   {
     products = value;
     OnPropertyChanged("Products");
   }
}
```

But how is that in C# 6.0? because the new style is with lambda operator:

```
ObservableCollection<Product> products;
public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
{ 
  get => products; 
  set => products= value; 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Auto-Implemented Properties* (auto-properties) have existed since c# 3.

```
public int Age { get; set; }
```

C# 6 do some improvements, one of them was the *Auto-Property Initializers*.

```
public int Age { get; } = 30;
```

But I think what you want to use is another feature, the *Expression-bodied function members*

```
public void SayHello(string name) => Console.WriteLine("hello {0}", name);

public string FullName => string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
```

**Expression-bodied function members**
The body of a lot of members that we write consist of **only one statement** that can be represented as an expression. You can reduce that syntax by writing an expression-bodied member instead. It works for methods and **read-only properties**.

[Expression-bodied function members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#expression-bodied-function-members)

You can't use use them in your case, because your property is not read-only.

Maybe this can help you.
[How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in C# 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582162/how-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged-in-c-sharp-6-0)

**UPDATE:**

C# 7 introduces the syntax you want, but only for single-line expressions.

**Property set statements**([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#property-set-statements))
If you choose to implement a property set accessor yourself, you can use an expression body definition for a **single-line expression** that assigns a value to the field that backs the property.

```
public class Location
{
   private string locationName;

   public Location(string name) => Name = name;

   public string Name
   {
      get => locationName;
      set => locationName = value;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I have to use the old style:                              
   set
   {
     products = value;
     OnPropertyChanged("Products");
   }